# HttpPostedFileBase always null on file upload, model bound error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to upload a file via JQuery Ajax to an ASP.NET Core MVC application.

The `HttpPostedFileBase` is always `null`. When I put it as a parameter directly in the action I'm getting a model bound error.

Javascript:

```
$(document).on('click', '#attachItemBtn', function () {
    var attachItemFiles = document.getElementById('attachItemFile');

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("Document", attachItemFiles.files[0]);
    formData.append("Id", 1234);
    formData.append("FileName", "test");

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
        url: App.Urls.AddAttachment,
        success: function (data) {
            App.Messages.showErrorMessage('Item attached');
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            App.Messages.showErrorMessage('Error Occured While attaching document');
        }
    });

    var debug = 0;
});
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddAttachment(AttachmentItemModel model)
{
    var count = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files.Count;
    int i = 0;
    return Json("done");
}
```

Model:

```
public class AttachmentItemModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase Document { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

The above code works with `HttpContext.Request.Form.Files` but the `model.Document` is `null`

When I re-write the Action to the below function signature I get an error:

```
public IActionResult AddAttachment(int Id, string FileName, System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase Document)
```

I then get the below error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>       InvalidOperationException: Could not create an instance of type 
>       'System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase'. Model bound complex types must not be 
>       abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor.

**What am I missing?**  I would prefer the file(s) be bound in my model instead of using `HttpContext.Request.Files`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How'd you even get `HttpPostedFileBase` to resolve? Regardless, it doesn't exist in ASP.NET Core. Instead, you should be using `IFormFile`.